# Why do I get a recursion error with BeautifulSoup and IDLE?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-idle

I am following a tutorial to try to learn how to use BeautifulSoup. I am trying to remove names from the urls on a html page I downloaded. I have it working great to this point.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("43rd-congress.html"))

final_link = soup.p.a
final_link.decompose()

links = soup.find_all('a')

for link in links:
    print link
```

but when I enter this next part

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("43rd-congress.html"))

final_link = soup.p.a
final_link.decompose()

links = soup.find_all('a')

for link in links:
    names = link.contents[0]
    fullLink = link.get('href')
    print names
    print fullLink
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/python tutorials/soupexample.py", line 13, in <module>
    print names
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1325, in write
    return self.shell.write(s, self.tags)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 595, in __call__
    value = self.sockio.remotecall(self.oid, self.name, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 210, in remotecall
    seq = self.asynccall(oid, methodname, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 225, in asynccall
    self.putmessage((seq, request))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 324, in putmessage
    s = pickle.dumps(message)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\copy_reg.py", line 74, in _reduce_ex
    getstate = self.__getstate__
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: I suspect that `print str(names)` *will* work; IDLE and BeautifulSoup objects may not play well together.

Comment: Confirmed: http://bugs.python.org/issue1757057, this is a bad interaction here with IDLE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a buggy interaction between IDLE and BeautifulSoup's `NavigableString` objects (which subclass `unicode`). See [issue 1757057](http://bugs.python.org/issue1757057); it's been around for a while.

The work-around is to convert the object to a plain unicode value first:

```
print unicode(names)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was getting insane with this issue. The [same bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14638) is now filed for PyCharm (3.4 at least).