# To use BeautifulSoup to extract parts of texts in webpage title

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the title text on this page http://www.arizona.edu/colleges/college-agriculture-life-sciences.

Here’s the code I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2

url = "http://www.arizona.edu/colleges/college-agriculture-life-sciences"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

uni_name=soup.title

print uni_name
```

however the result is:

```
<title>College of Agriculture &amp; Life Sciences | The University of Arizona, Tucson, Arizona</title>
```

But what my ideal result is:

```
College of Agriculture & Life Sciences
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.string` attribute gives you just the tag text:

```
uni_name = soup.title.string
```

If you want to use only the first part, split on the `|` pipe:

```
uni_name = soup.title.string.partition('|')[0].strip()
```

This uses [`str.partition()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to split just once (for efficiency), takes the first part of the result, and removes any extra whitespace around that result.

Demo:

```
>>> soup.title
<title>College of Agriculture &amp; Life Sciences | The University of Arizona, Tucson, Arizona</title>
>>> soup.title.string
u'College of Agriculture & Life Sciences | The University of Arizona, Tucson, Arizona'
>>> soup.title.string.partition('|')[0].strip()
u'College of Agriculture & Life Sciences'
```

Comment: thanks Martijn for the super fast reply. but it gives an error message here - RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp. is it because i am using Python 2.7?

Comment: @MarkK: I tested this in Python 2.7 myself; what version of BeautifulSoup are you using?

Comment: I'll also note that "for efficiency* - `str.partition` is not far off being twice as fast in this case...

Comment: @JonClements: mumble mumble `str.partition`-shmartition mumble muble.

Comment: @MarkK: what is the traceback for that exception? Perhaps best to use a gist or pastie for that.

Comment: @MarkK: I used 4.3.2. `import bs4; print bs4.__version__`.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, seems i got you wrong - thinking you asked me to paste the error message here..

Comment: @MarkK: comments are not a good place for tracebacks. Use a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [pastie](http://pastie.org/) instead.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, they are new to me. I've put it on pastie, am looking forward to see what's coming. :)

Comment: Pastie is a tool to share a chunk of text; you now need to give me the url to that text here in a comment :-)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, thanks for saving my sweating forehead. it's  http://pastie.org/pastes/8641644

Comment: Ah, that's a known bug in IDLE: [Why Do I Get an Error With Python Beautiful Soup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19578749) Use `print unicode(uni_name)` to work around that.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, this's brilliant! it works. thank you again for the help. wish you a great weekend.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this library ([Goose](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose)).

I tried to create my own extractors for a few websites with beautifulsoup, but then I realize that Goose does exactly what I need.